# print dynamically generated checkbox selected rows from datagridview to crystal report on another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, crystal-reports

I have dynamically added checkboxes for each row in datagridview (form1)and i am trying to generate crystal report on a new form (form 2) for only those rows whose checkbox is checked.

My code on form1 button click is

```
private void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//im trying to insert selected rows in datatable which is datasource for crystal report   
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
  int i = 1;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
//dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["select"].Value)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; ++j)
            {
                table.Rows[i][j] = row.Cells[j].Value;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        if (cb_reptype.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Individual")
        {
    //here im specifying the path for new form2
          string path = table.ToString();//dataGridView1.SelectedRows[1].Cells["table"].Value.ToString();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(path);
            //ReportDocument crystal = new ReportDocument();
            //crystal.Load(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ReportPath"].Value.ToString());
            //pass = crystal;
            f2.Show();

        }
```

and my code on form2 is

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string source;
    public Form2(string path)
    {
        source = path;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = source;
    }
}
```

on debugging the program and button click event , new form is opening but it is showing below error.

I have tried a lot of research on this topic but not upto the mark.

Kindly reply as soon as possible.. Thanks :)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try providing valid document in Form constructor inside button click event.
Valid document could be .xml, .rpt file for generating crystal report.

For the current scenario do few additions:

```
if (cb_reptype.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Individual")
{
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ds.Tables.Add(table);
  ds.WriteXmlSchema("Drive:\\Somefolder\\Sample.xml"); // this generates Xml file.
```

Now pass this path to Form constructor as this is valid report file.

```
  Form f2 = new Form("Drive:\\Somefolder\\Sample.xml");
  f2.show();
}
```

You need to add rows to DataTable before adding any value from datagrid.

```
while(table.Rows.Count<dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count)
{
  table.Rows.Add();
}
```

Once done with this you can add values from datagrid:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
  for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; ++j)
  {
    table.Rows[i][j] = row.Cells[j].Value;
  }
  ++i;
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: it will take writexml, but i dont think my foreach loop is taking any values from datagrid.
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in **dataGridView1.SelectedRows**)
here i want records which are checked in **select** column(is it possible like this)
//dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["select"].Value)